# Printing a javascript variable in php echo

Tags: php, javascript, variables

To clarify:

I have an echo statement as follows:

```
 $striptitle .= ' - <a onclick="getnewurl();" href="'.SGLink::album($aid). '">'. $namek .'</a></h1>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-via="jb_thehot" data-text="Pictures of '. $hashfinal .'" teens>Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>';

echo $striptitle ;
```

The onclick does this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getnewurl()
{
var url = document.URL;
alert( url );
}
</script>
```

What I need is essentially to add the my anchor tag a data-url="INSERT_VAR_URL_HERE"

Is that possible?

Let me know if this isn't clear enough
Thanks!

Edit: to clarify, the alert in the function is only for testing. What I need is to be able to use the variable obtained in the function, in the same $striptitle variable.

My problem is that the url changes with AJAX, and the twitter button's data-url does not get updated. I was hoping to be able to get the new url by getting it everytime it is clicked. If there are other ways to do that, I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, why do you need to set the `data-url` attribute?

Comment: Just edited my question, let me know if it's not clear enough!

Comment: what you have described in the first part of your edit sounds quite clearly impossible --- you want to use a JS variable which only exists on the client and only after the php has finished executing in the php running on the server. To do what you want would require a time machine.

Comment: alternatively you cna change the data-url attribute purely in JS, however `data-*` attributes are special. I'd recommend using jQuery to handle the nastiness there.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thanks for clarifying. This whole thing was an attempt at fixing my main problem; people navigate away from the original url using AJAX, so the tweet count and url still share the original url, not the updated one. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it as an argument?

```
$striptitle .= " - <a onclick=\"getnewurl('URL-HERE');\"...>";
```

Then in your script:

```
<script>
    function getnewurl(url) {
        alert(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I should have mentionned @Kolink , the alert is only for testing purposes and is going away. Wouldn't I still need to set the variable url with document.URL in my function?

Comment: Then how would I pass it in a data-text="variablehere" ?

Comment: Pass `this` as an argument, and then get its attribute with `getAttribute("data-text")`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following; my knowledge of javascript is very limited and I don't know what "this" or getAttribute does :/

Comment: I've edited my question, perhaps that explains better what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Kolink's answer one way to not repeat the url in two places you could generate the link as:

```
<a onclick="getnewurl(this);" href="...">
```

then your JS could look like:

```
function getnewurl(link) {
    link.setAttribute('data-url', location.href);
}
```

**EDIT** apparently `jQuery.data` doesn't update the dom properly, but setAttribute does

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly my issue I think. I've edited my question for further clarification!

Comment: Thanks again for the updates, the data-url does not seem to be updated at all :/ This whole thing was an attempt at fixing my main problem; people navigate away from the original url using AJAX, so the tweet count and url still share the original url, not the updated one. Any ideas on that?

Comment: this code should fix that for you --- the `data-url` will be updated in the DOM. (though obviously the original html will not change, but that sould not matter)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's working or not - since the html doesn't change, and the result in the twitter pop-up doesn't seem to change. The updated url gets an #some-more-stuff appended to it, I don't know if the # messes things up?